# Iphone input fields showing inner shadow

Tags: css, iphone

I am using `input[type="text"]` or `input[type="password"]` in my HTML, but when I test the code on iphone, there showing small inner shadow at the top. I have tried `box-shadow: none;`

Comment: are you using an older version of safari or iOS?

Comment: did you try the -webkit prefix, though it shouldn't be needed past iOS 5.0

Comment: @gro: I have tried '-webkit-box-shadow: none;'

Comment: how about -webkit-appearance: none;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

`input[type="text"], input[type="password"]:-webkit-appearance: none;`